# Dapper SqlDateTime overflow using GETDATE() in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-3, dapper

I have the following code which gets the input from a form and calls a stored procedure to store it in a database.

```
 [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Index(GuestMessage model)
 {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            using(IDbConnection conn = DatabaseAcess.OpenConnection())
            {
                const string storedProcedure = "dbo.InsertMessage";
                conn.Execute(storedProcedure, new GuestMessage { Name = model.Name, Email = model.Email, Message = model.Message }, null, null, CommandType.StoredProcedure);

                return View("ThankYou");
            }
         }
        return View();
}
```

There are three fields, `Name`, `E-mail` and `Message` that have to be filled in by the user. In the database I store the data that the user enters, from these three fields, and the time of the entry using a stored function called dbo.Insert Message.

```
BEGIN
  BEGIN TRAN

  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @GuestID int;
  INSERT INTO Guest(Name, Email) VALUES (@Name, @Email);
  SELECT @GuestID = scope_identity();

  INSERT INTO Message (EntryDate, GuestID, Message, Status) 
  VALUES (GETDATE(), @GuestID, @Message, 2);

  COMMIT TRAN
END
```

Notice that I do not pass the entry date and time as an input parameter to the stored procedure since there is no need for that. I use the built-in function `GETDATE()` in SQL Server to determine the time a user has entered a message.

However, whenever I try to enter a message I get the following error:

> SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59PM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest the following change:

```
conn.Execute(storedProcedure,
    new { Name = model.Name, Email = model.Email, Message = model.Message },
    commandType: CommandType.StoredProcedure);
```

The only *actual* change there is that I have swapped `new GuestMessage { ... }` for `new { ... }`. What I *suspect* is happening is that your `GuestMessage` type has additional properties that *aren't needed*, but which it is sending as parameters. A `DateTime` left at its default value is "00:00:00.0000000, January 1, 0001". By swapping to just `new { ... }`, we have *explicitly limited* the members we are sending to `Name`, `Email` and `Message`, because *those are the only things defined*.

Note: when using plain-text, dapper does use some voodoo to try to see which parameter names are actually used in the SQL, and it doesn't send anything that it **knows** isn't referenced in the SQL - however, it cannot do this with a stored procedure.

Comment: You are right, I changed new GuestMessage { ... } to new { ... } and it worked. There is some voodoo behind Dapper since I never pass the date parameter from the GuestMessage object to the stored procedure. The stored procedure does not even expect to see a DateTime. In order to set the DateTime i use the SQL server built in function GETDATE(). Thanks a lot